# How to copy row based on cell value to another sheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to copy 2 columns( A and B ) from sheetA to sheetB, based on each different value of column D from sheetA.
I get the week number from "release date" but now i need to create into sheetB 2 columns for each different "week number" and copy the 2 first columns on each week.

I'm getting week numbers using:

```
If IsDate(c.Value) Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = Format(c.Value, "ww")
```

But i don't know how to store each different value on "WEEK_NUM" to create the column on sheetB and then copy the row...

That's what i'm trying to obtain:
[image: copy_weeks]

Comment: You could get a list of unique week numbers, loop through, extract the 2 columns using autofilter, copy across etc.

Comment: Ok, but how can i apply an autofilter for each value ok week number? and how i can take the "week number" and then create 2 columns ( and copy the filtered values ) for each week? thanks!